# android javax mail messaging exception could not connect to smtp host network unreachable

Tags: android, jakarta-mail, socketexception

I am new to Android development, trying to develop a simple app that sends email automatically using javax mail. I tried with several codes for both SSL & TSL (port no 465 & 587) with adding respective properties. But still it returns me with error `invalid IPv6 type or code from... ,messaging exception, could not connect to smtp host, network unreachable...`. Anyone please help me with some solutions. 
I am adding my code fragments below:

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button b;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
        .permitAll().build();

    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                new SendSync().execute();

            }
        });
    }


    public class SendSync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {

        String error;
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub..

            try {   
              GMailSender sender = new GMailSender("xyz@gmail.com", "pqrst");
              sender.sendMail("This is Subject",   
                      "This is Body",   
                      "xyz@gmail.com",   
                      "abcd@gmail.com");  

          } catch (Exception e) {   
              error=e.getMessage();
              Log.e("SendMail", e.getMessage(), e);   
              System.out.println("exception "+e);

          }
            return null; 


        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if(error!=null)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ERROR!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                System.out.println("exception "+error);
            }


        }   
    }
```

Gmailsender class:

```
public class GMailSender  extends javax.mail.Authenticator{

    private String mailhost = "smtp.gmail.com";   
    private String user;   
    private String password;   
    private Session session;   

    static {   
        Security.addProvider(new com.provider.JSSEProvider());   
    }  

    public GMailSender(String user, String password) {   
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
        .permitAll().build();

    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        this.user = user;   
        this.password = password;   

        Properties props = new Properties();   
//        props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");   
//        props.setProperty("mail.host", mailhost);   
//        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");   
//        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");   
//        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");   
//        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",   
//                "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");   
//        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
//        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");   
//        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");   
       props.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Stack", "true");


        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        props.put("mail.debug", "false"); 
        props.put("java.net.preferIPv4Stack", "true");
        session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props

                , new javax.mail.Authenticator(){
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication("xyz@gmail.com", "pqrst");// Specify the Username and the PassWord
            }
    });  
//        
    }   

//    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {   
//        return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);   
//    }  


    public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body, String sender, String recipients) throws Exception {   
        try{
            //SmtpAuthenticator authentication = new SmtpAuthenticator();
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);   
        DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));   
        message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));   
        message.setSubject(subject);   
        message.setDataHandler(handler);   
        if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)   
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipients));   
        else  
            message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));   


        Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtps");
        transport.connect(mailhost, 587, user, password);
        transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
        transport.close();


        //Transport.send(message);

        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("AAAA mailsender exception "+e);
        }
    }


    public class ByteArrayDataSource implements DataSource {   
        private byte[] data;   
        private String type;   

        public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data, String type) {   
            super();   
            this.data = data;   
            this.type = type;   
        }   

        public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data) {   
            super();   
            this.data = data;   
        }   

        public void setType(String type) {   
            this.type = type;   
        }   

        public String getContentType() {   
            if (type == null)   
                return "application/octet-stream";   
            else  
                return type;   
        }   

        public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {   
            return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);   
        }   

        public String getName() {   
            return "ByteArrayDataSource";   
        }   

        public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {   
            throw new IOException("Not Supported");   
        }   
    }   
}
```

Here is the logcat messages i got:

```
02-20 11:43:38.804: I/System.out(31376): propertyValue:true
02-20 11:43:38.805: I/System.out(31376): [socket][4] connection smtp.gmail.com/2404:6800:4003:c00::6d:587;LocalPort=54051(0)
02-20 11:43:38.805: I/System.out(31376): [CDS]connect[smtp.gmail.com/2404:6800:4003:c00::6d:587] tm:90
02-20 11:43:38.805: D/Posix(31376): [Posix_connect Debug]Process com.example.mailtest :587 
02-20 11:43:38.822: I/dhcpcd(5854): dhcpcd[5855]: invalid IPv6 type or code from fe80::f63e:61ff:fe48:4fd1
02-20 11:43:38.823: I/System.out(31376): [socket][5:54051] exception
02-20 11:43:38.823: I/System.out(31376): [CDS]close[54051]
02-20 11:43:38.823: I/System.out(31376):mailsender exception javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 587;
02-20 11:43:38.823: I/System.out(31376):   nested exception is:
02-20 11:43:38.824: I/System.out(31376):    java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to smtp.gmail.com/2404:6800:4003:c00::6d (port 587) after 90000ms: isConnected failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)
02-20 11:43:38.828: I/NotificationService(492): enqueueToast pkg=com.example.mailtest callback=android.app.ITransientNotification$Stub$Proxy@42bb7948 duration=1
```

Comment: Is internet connected? Do you have this permission in AndroidManifest `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Comment: Looks like you copy and pasted the code from someone who didn't know what they were doing.  There's lots of problems with your code, although none of them explain the error you're getting.  Where exactly is this code running?  In an Android phone?

Comment: i got this code fragment from the same stackoverflow site which is recommended by someone for sending email in android application, i created the sample app and i got this error while i am trying to run it on an android device.

Comment: the phone is connected to Internet and permission above mentioned are already added.